# Azure DB disconnections and connection timout

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-web-app-service, tedious

We're having "storms" of DB disconnections and connections timeouts once every couple of days.

We're running Node.js on Azure WebApps and using [tedious](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tedious) to connect SQL Azure, any ideas where to start looking for the problem?

Comment: Hello Guy, Tedious -https://github.com/pekim/tedious is maintained by the community. If you feel that the issue is the driver than it  might be a better idea posting this as an issue on Github.
However if you feel like the issue is on database engine side, I would love to help. Can you share your error log/error number or any other information that can help us figure out the problem.

Comment: @meet-bhagdev thanks, we're pretty sure it's AuzreSQL fault.
```
  "@message": "database connection error:  {\"name\":\"ConnectionError\",\"message\":\"Failed to connect to xxx.database.windows.net:1433 in 15000ms\",\"code\":\"ETIMEOUT\"}",
```

Comment: Have you implemented some kind of retry policy to deal with transients connection failures?

Comment: Sure, but it doesn't help we get these errors in a row for 10m-15m.

Comment: SQL DB recommends connection timeout of 30s instead of 15s default. Could you try setting that? Also these are transient and you may want to retry them

Comment: Why does it take so long , so many times?

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you are having timeouts. Unfortunately retry logic is required. Using the correct retry policy should help you fix/mitigate your timeouts and downtime. 

Here is what I would recommend :

```
int connectionTimeoutSeconds = 30;  // Default of 15 seconds is too short over the Internet, sometimes.
int maxCountTriesConnectAndQuery = 3;  // You can adjust the various retry count values.
int secondsBetweenRetries = 4;  // Simple retry strategy.
```

[Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/ee336243.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) is the sample code for C#, you should be to replicate in Javascript and that should mitigate your timeouts and downtime.

If that does not fix the issue, please email your servername and dbname at mebha at microsoft dot com and I will have one of our engineers look at it.

Best,

Meet Bhagdev

Program Manager, Microsoft

Comment: why do I need 30sec, both the DB and the server are running in the same site, I can't make consumers wait 30sec or even more...

Comment: The way AzureSQL DB currently works is that you are able to directly communicate with your database. Previously you used to have a middleman(proxy) that used to facilitate the communication.This used to cause latency issues and thereby we removed it.As a result, if a fail over occurs you loose the connection and there is not proxy that can hold the connection for you.Thus u need to retry.Usually you will be able to establish the connection again once you retry.The 30 seconds is the server side recommendation that we came up with after doing a lot of testing.You should definitely experiment :)

Comment: Also it would be great if you look at this link - https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-connect-central-recommendations/. There are some recommendations here and one of them is about transient errors and retry logic. Do let me know if this clarifies something or if you have any other questions. Happy to help.

Comment: I did all the changes but again... We started getting the following:
```
    "@message": "on uncaughtException: connect ETIMEDOUT,\n\nError: connect ETIMEDOUT\n    at errnoException (net.js:904:11)\n    at Object.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:895:19)",
```

Comment: Hi Guy, can you please send me your server name and database name. Additionally can you also send me your retry logic code? My email address is mebha at microsoft dot com. I will engage the engineering team to have a look at it.